# Gem installed. Gem's command is not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed the `ruby-processing` gem using:

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-processing
```

When I try to run `ruby-processing`'s `rp5` command, this is the output I get:

```
rp5 run twitter_emotion_graphs.rb 
No command 'rp5' found, did you mean:
Command 'rpm' from package 'rpm' (main)
Command 'rpl' from package 'rpl' (universe)
rp5: command not found
```

Here's the context for more information (have a look at the README) :
https://github.com/vishrut/Twitter-Emotion-Graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some systems (e.g., Debian) the path where the gem executables are installed to are not in the `$PATH`. Dependingmon your distribution, that path is on a different location, on Debian with the system Ruby, it is at `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`. To add that to the system's `$PATH`, put something like this into a new file in `/etc/profile.d/rubygems.sh`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the executable is on your path. You may have to restart your terminal for everything to refresh.

Comment: Solved. That was the problem.